# Linux mint 17 enable OPENVPN service

Tags: linux-mint

I am trying to enable my openvpn using this command: `sudo systemctl enable openvpn@serviceName.service` but i have this msg - `systemctl: command not found`. I saw that Linux Mint 17 do not support this systemctl service and i do not know which one i have to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SysV init system.

```
insserv -v openvpn@serviceName
```

And to remove from boot

```
insserv -rv openvpn@serviceName
```

Comment: I have - insserv not found When i put it in terminal.